# Get Sales Information MWS API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-mws

I am using Amazon MWS API to get Sales information. How do I get the ASIN, Purchase date, Quantity sold information.How can i get it any Suggested Report or api reference. please help

Answer (score 1):

You can get via **ListOrders API** or **_GET_ORDERS_DATA_** report.

You can find different API and reports from below link.

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__OrderReports

Answer (score 0):

I found following link which provides all report description and response type.it is very help full for beginners of MWS for Report.

https://sellerstoolbox.com/report-types/